# Como obter ultima sequence no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu tentei de 3 formas diferentes, fazer um `select` da ultima `sequence` da minha tabela, porém nenhuma deu certo.

> SELECT SEQ_ID_PAIS.CURRVAL FROM DUAL;

Erro:

```
 ORA-08002: a sequência SEQ_ID_PAIS.CURRVAL ainda não foi definida nesta sessão
08002. 00000 -  "sequence %s.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session"
```

> SELECT LAST_NUMBER FROM SEQ_ID_PAIS;

Erro:

```
 ORA-02201: sequência não permitida aqui
    02201. 00000 -  "sequence not allowed here"
```

> SELECT LAST_VALUE FROM SEQ_ID_PAIS;

Erro:

```
ORA-02201: sequência não permitida aqui
02201. 00000 -  "sequence not allowed here"
```

qual seria a maneira correta de obter este valor ?

Comment: @Articuno eu achava que o erro era no codigo em java, mais percebi, que meu descuido foi no sql, então refiz a pergunta.

Comment: Dica: não há necessidade de ficar apagando e recriando a mesma pergunta. Se ninguém te respondeu, é porque sua pergunta ou não está muito clara ou porque ninguem que domine o tema ainda viu a pergunta. **Tenha paciência** e sempre que possível, edite e melhore a pergunta, um hora alguém responde.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora08002.php       acho que a "currval" só pode ser chamada após a "nextval" , qual razão de saber a última sequence antes de usá-la !?

Comment: @Motta vou imprimir em um tela como ID.

Comment: Ok , faça então após o "nextval".

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem, vou ter que fazer 2 selects ?

Answer (score 2):

O comando CURRVAL é apenas para a sessão que a sequense foi executada, então você não terá mais esse valor.

Você pode tentar para ver a estrutura dela,

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_sequences
 WHERE sequence_name = 'nome_da_sua_sequence';
```

não conseguindo, você pode procurar a tabela que ela e utilizada para o `insert` e verificar o `MAX` do campo.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser retornar logo apos a inserção você pode fazer assim:

```
insert into SIG_PROJETOAGRUPAMENTOSERVICO
  (idagrupamentoservico, descricao)
values
  (sq_Sig_Projagrupamentoserv.nextval, :nomeAgrupamento)
 returning idagrupamentoservico into :idagrupamento
```

Desta forma sua consuta ira retornar o valor inserido.

Caso queira acessa-lo depois basta fazer assim:

```
SELECT last_number
  FROM user_sequences
 WHERE sequence_name = '<sequence_name>';
```

Comment: da erro, eu tentei assim: SELECT last_number  FROM PAIS  WHERE sequence_name = '<SEQ_ID_PAIS>'; ele me retorna : ORA-00904: "SEQ_ID_PAIS": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 1 Coluna: 38

Comment: Isso costuma ser erro de sintax, tira uma print e envia aqui de como ta fazendo a consulta. Se possível coloca na pergunta as sql se criação das tabelas, para que eu possa recriar o ambiente aqui e simular.

Comment: SELECT last_number FROM user_sequences WHERE sequence_name = 'SEQ_ID_PAIS'